# sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo

I set an alias for sudo as:

```
alias sudo='sudo PATH=$MY_PATH'
```

I checked that this works well by running `sudo printenv PATH`.

However, I encounter an error when running `sudo su - USER2`.

> sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: PATH

I could find a workaround by running `sudo -i su - USER2`, but I want to know why this error occurs.

I referred to https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.28/sudoers.man.html#Denied_command_log_entries but couldn't get the reason.

> sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables
>
> > The user specified environment variables on the command line that were not allowed by sudoers.

Why is PATH denied by sudoers only when using `su` command?

Any link or comment appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is on [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/648265/108618).

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this even in sudoers file.

I needed to execute command

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

I solved it by setting this to sudoers.d/file

```
byznys_mail_sender ALL=NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/bin/apt install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

SETENV is the key for this. It allows user to modify environment. https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.32/sudoers.man/#SETENV

Answer (score 3):

Sudo restricts the environment variables that users may set because environment variables can influence the behavior of a program. `PATH` is especially dangerous since it can cause a different program to be executed. This is relevant when the user only has the permission to run specific commands, but not when the user has the permission to run arbitrary commands.

If you have permission to run arbitrary commands, a simple workaround is to run `env`.

```
sudo env PATH="$MY_PATH" …
```

---

Setting `PATH` and then invoking `su - USER2` doesn't make sense: `su -` will usually overwrite (or sometimes only extend) `PATH`, so you wouldn't be getting the normal environment of `USER2`. Furthermore, `sudo su - USER2` is needless complication since `sudo -i -u USER2` will do.

Comment: Then why does `sudo PATH=$PATH ls` work fine while `sudo PATH=$PATH su - USER2` occurs an error? I wonder why `sudo` + `su` denies setting env variable, while some other commands work well.